# Why drupal_realpath('public://') returns an incorrect path?

Tags: 7, files

I am calling `drupal_realpath('public://')` inside a module function.

Why am I getting a path like sites/all/modules/current_module/sites/default/files from `drupal_realpath('public://')`?

Comment: Question - what PHP version are you using?
it is strongly recommended not to use drupal_realpath(), but use alternative for it. I would suggest you the alternative, but it's not clear what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`drupal_realpath()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/drupal_realpath/7) has been deprecated and shouldn't be used; since you have a stream wrapper URI you should be able to get the correct path like this:

```
$uri = 'public://';
if ($wrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($uri)) {
  $path = $wrapper->realpath();
}
```

Also make sure that your public path is correct in the UI (at admin/config/media/file-system)

Comment: Thanks for info, anyway I have still the same (wrong) path. Under admin/config/media/file-system I have public path set to: sites/default/files

Comment: Very strange; what sort of path do you get if you try a test like this: `$path = file_create_url('public://test.txt');`?

Comment: It gives me: http://C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp/sites/default/files/test.txt

Comment: And is that the right path to your public files folder?

Comment: This is path to temporary directory (C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp) from admin/config/media/file-system page

Comment: Are you sure you haven't got your public and temp folders mixed up on the admin page? That would make a lot of sense

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Clive's anwser using:

```
$path = $wrapper->getExternalUrl();
```

Instead of using:

```
$path = $wrapper->realpath();
```

Worked for me, I had the same problem with the wrong path.

Comment: For future readers: `$wrapper->getExternalUrl()` returns a URL. Only [`DrupalPublicStreamWrapper::getExternalUrl()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21stream_wrappers.inc/function/DrupalPublicStreamWrapper%3A%3AgetExternalUrl/7.x) returns a relative URL for the site running Drupal, which can then be used as path, but other stream wrappers could return an absolute URL which cannot be used as path, as [`DrupalPrivateStreamWrapper::getExternalUrl()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21stream_wrappers.inc/function/DrupalPrivateStreamWrapper%3A%3AgetExternalUrl/7.x) does.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal uses PHP's file stream and the path is configured in this location

```
admin/config/media/file-system
```

You can change it to where ever you want

Comment: It is set to sites/default/files so it look ok