# How do I get the path for public://

Tags: 7, files

I need to get the path for public:// at runtime. Is there a function I can use to get it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the following code, to obtain the real path of public://.

```
if ($wrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri('public://')) {
  $realpath = $wrapper->realpath();
  // ...
}
```

This code is the simplified version of the code used by `file_create_url()`, with the following differences:

- It doesn't allow third-party modules to alter the URL, since the OP is asking for the path associated with public://
- It doesn't check the URI contains ://, since this is clearly true
- It doesn't check the URI is a root-relative URI, since this is clearly false for public://
- It doesn't check the URI is protocol relative, since this is clearly false in the OP's case
- It doesn't check the URI is not a properly formatted stream, since public:// is a properly formatted stream
- It doesn't check if the scheme is http or https, since in this case is public
- It doesn't call `$wrapper->getExternalUrl()` since the OP is asking for the path, not for the URL

If the OP wanted the URL for public://, I would have used the following code, which is still a simplified version of the code used by the Drupal function, which needs to be more generic.

```
if ($wrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri('public://')) {
  $url = $wrapper->getExternalUrl();
}
```

Answer (score 42):

You can use the [file_create_url](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) function.

```
$uri = 'public://';
$path= file_create_url($uri)
```

Comment: This gets you the url, but including the server. I used a simple regex and the `global $base_url` to remove it and make this server agnostic.
`global $base_url;
        $path = file_create_url($file_object->uri);
        $path = preg_replace('#' . $base_url . '#', '', $path);`
Make sure to use the '#' in the regex, otherwise the replace will fail due to an un-escaped '/' in the $base_url.

Comment: The OP asked for the path, not the URL.

Answer (score 24):

In case if you are using only local files (**not remote!**) you can also try [drupal_realpath()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/drupal_realpath/7)

```
$path = 'public://custom_map';
drupal_realpath($path);
```

It will return:

```
D:\Work\OpenServer\domains\local.testsite.com\sites\default\files\custom_map
```

Comment: This returns a path and not a URL, which is what the question asks for. In my opinion this is better than the accepted answer.

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/drupal_realpath/7 . drupal_realpath() is deprecated as seen in the comments.

Comment: @Wordzilla, well it's not. If you will check latest Drupal source you will find it's usage in big amount of places, it's not deprecated but it's usage must be restricted. Documentation in *file.inc* says that it is "discouraged", but not deprecated.

Comment: @ScottJoudry The OP asks for _the path for public://_, not the URL.

Comment: @Wordzilla: The docs don't say it's deprecated; they said it's discouraged because it only handles local file paths (which the public filesystem would be). From the docs: "Only use this function if you know that the stream wrapper in the URI uses the local file system, and you need to pass an absolute path to a function that is incompatible with stream URIs."

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I believe that ScottJoudry was making the same point if you read what he wrote again. He was saying that this answer is more on-point for the OP, whereas the accepted answer is not.

Comment: @GuyPaddock Thanks for the correction. Unfortunately, I can't edit the comment now.

Comment: No problem. Just wanted to help clarify this since I ran into it the other day.

Answer (score 3):

See the following examples:

```
$scheme = file_uri_scheme($file);

if ($scheme && file_stream_wrapper_valid_scheme($scheme)) {
  $wrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_scheme($scheme);
  $path = $wrapper->getLocalPath($file);
}
```

or:

```
$wrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($uri);
$path = $wrapper->getDirectoryPath() . "/" . file_uri_target($uri);
print $path;
```

Check API for [`DrupalPublicStreamWrapper`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!stream_wrappers.inc/class/DrupalPublicStreamWrapper/7).

Using `file_create_url()` doesn't work in all cases (as the other answers suggest), because the returned URL doesn't have to be on the same server. And using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` works only for certain server configurations.

If you don't want to use stream wrappers, you may try simpler solution:

```
$path = variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path() . '/files') . '/' . file_uri_target($uri);
```

Otherwise if you need something that works more generally, check [@hannanxp's](https://www.drupal.org/node/837794#comment-6517308) solution:

```
$wrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($uri);
if ($wrapper instanceof DrupalLocalStreamWrapper) {
  $path = $wrapper->getDirectoryPath() . '/' . file_uri_target($uri);
}
else {
  // This does not appear to be a local file so there's no such thing as
  // a relative path; do appropriate error handling here.
}
```

Read more: [How can I convert a file uri to relative path?](https://www.drupal.org/node/837794#comment-9124435)

---

Related:

- [Why drupal_realpath('public://') returns sites/all/modules/current_module/sites/default/files path?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45299/why-drupal-realpathpublic-returns-sites-all-modules-current-module-sites)
- [How do I get the public url of a file from the uri or filename](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59880/how-do-i-get-the-public-url-of-a-file-from-the-uri-or-filename)