# How do I get the public url of a file from the uri or filename

Tags: 7, files, uri

I'm using php from with a view ([Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php)) I'm trying to extract the real url of a file from a file reference. I am able to get the the uri of the file and or the filename. What drupal function can I use to get thee actual public URL of the file?.

```
$videouri = db_query('SELECT filename FROM `file_managed` WHERE fid = ' . $nidvideo)->fetchColumn();
//drupal_set_message('<pre>'. print_r($videourl, TRUE) .'</pre>');
$realpath = drupal_realpath($videouri);
$videourl = file_create_url($realpath);
return($videourl);
```

Answer (score 20):

What do you mean by "public URL" exactly ?

[file_create_url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) can give the absolute URL to the image out of the box.

```
$videouri = db_query('SELECT uri FROM {file_managed} WHERE fid = :nidvideo', array(':nidvideo' => $nidvideo))->fetchColumn();
//drupal_set_message('<pre>'. print_r($videourl, TRUE) .'</pre>');
$videourl = file_create_url($videouri);
```

`file_create_url()` expects a valid uri. `drupal_realpath()` gives the server path which does not work.

I also changed your database query to avoid any SQL injection vulnerable.

Answer (score 10):

Don't use `drupal_realpath()` as it has been [deprecated](https://api.drupal.org/comment/32833#comment-32833) now.

Either of the following can be used:

**1**. (`file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($uri)`):

```
$uri = $field[0]['uri'];  // file path as uri: 'public://';
if ($wrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($uri)) {
  $path = $wrapper->realpath();
}
```

**2**. (`file_create_url($uri)`):

```
$uri = $node->field_video['und'][0]['uri'];  // file path as uri: 'public://';
$video_path = file_create_url($uri);
```

Comment: @user379468 Has the above solution worked for you, or if you found some better solution than please share. Thanks!!

Comment: This is a common misconception that is incorrect. `drupal_realpath()` is not deprecated -- it's just discouraged in cases where a path could be remote, since it only works for local paths. The first code snippet posted above is exactly what `drupal_realpath()` does under the hood.

Comment: To clarify: my comment is specific to Drupal 7. Either way, I still stand by my assertion that using the same code as what's inside a deprecated function is no better than just calling the deprecated function.

Answer (score 4):

Check the following example:

```
$url = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($filepath)->getExternalUrl()
```

See: [API for DrupalPublicStreamWrapper](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!stream_wrappers.inc/class/DrupalPublicStreamWrapper/7).

Related:

- [Why drupal_realpath('public://') returns sites/all/modules/current_module/sites/default/files path?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45299/why-drupal-realpathpublic-returns-sites-all-modules-current-module-sites)
- [How can I convert a file uri to relative path?](https://drupal.org/node/837794)

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8 you can use the `file_url_generator` service

```
Drupal::service('file_url_generator')->generateAbsoluteString($uri)
```

Because the `file_create_url($uri)` function is deprecated since 9.3:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2940031